# How to send text queries from java to my api.ai agent?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I have created an agent on [api.ai](https://api.ai/) and it is working well. Now I want to pass text queries to the agent from a java project and get response from it. Any help?

Comment: Which SDK are you trying to use? Have you added it to the classpath? If there's a REST API, you just make HTTP requests from Java and you don't need any SDK

Comment: Does this README not tell you how to use the code? https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-java-client/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Believe me, I followed it. But I am getting the error "Missing artifact ai.api:libai:jar:1.4.9"

Comment: The most annoying words in that tutorial are "If there are no errors, you can get the result ...". So, what if I have errors? What am I supposed to do? I followed the tutorial letter by letter.

Comment: Open a github issue, I guess

Comment: That missing artifact error is Maven / Gradle related, though... Change it to 1.4.8

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my android project.

```
final AIConfiguration config = new 
AIConfiguration("your key",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
    AIRequest request = new AIRequest("your text request");
    AIService aiService = AIService.getService("implement new AIService", config);

    try {
        aiService.textRequest(request);
    } catch (AIServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could not you tell me how to do it from java desktop? I want to create a desktop java application not a mobile application.

Comment: @Ahmed Those are just Java classes. Why do you think they would be any different?

Comment: It's because I do not know how to install and use the api.ai java SDK. Their tutorial is not detailed and very short. Did you manage to do it @cricket_007 ?